# How to determine for sure if Node.js server response is stopped?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

How can I determine if server.HttpResponse stopped without listenng to "end" or "close" events?

What I am trying to achieve is something like this:

```
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    var foo; // my event emitting object

    // ... something compilated happens here ...

    foo.onSomeEvent(function () {
        if (response.hasEnded) {
            // do something
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can check the `finished` property on the response object:

```
if (res.finished) {
  ...
}
```

(never used it myself, so not sure if there are any potential problems to take into consideration when using it)

Comment: Sorry, this response is the step forward but when response "close" event is triggered, sometimes "response.finished" is still false.

Comment: @MateuszCharytoniuk your questions seemed to suggest that you don't want to listen for any events, otherwise I would have suggested using the `finish` event

Comment: This is true but I needed to check somehow that it works. In my final code I do not want to listen to anything.

Comment: @MateuszCharytoniuk the `finish` event seems to always get fired after `finished` is set to true, so that should work.

Comment: @robertklep if i never write to response, does "res.finished" ever turn to "true", for example, when timeout?

Comment: @datdinhquoc I have no idea, you'd have to test that yourself I'm afraid.

Comment: @robertklep as tested, the "finished" event is not fired when not writing to response

Answer (score 3):

use

```
if(response.writableEnded){
   //doSomething();
}
```

response.finished is deprecated